# Facebook Opengraph TV Episode, TV Show, and Series?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am creating a website for a student tv station and want to use opengraph.

We will have shows, which contain series, which contain episodes.

Facebook currently has "TV Episode" and "TV Show" which I reckon should map onto our episodes and shows.

However I can't find a type "TV Series".

If I look at the properties that "TV Episode" contains though it contains an optional one called "video:series", and next to that it says it expects a type of "Series", but I can't find anything of type "Series" anywhere. This is a screenshot:[image: TV Episode Object Type Screenshot]

Does the "type" column map to an open graph type like "TV Episode" or is this a different type of type. If it's a type like, array, string, url etc then what is it because I've never heard of a "series" type in a programming language before and can't find it mentioned anywhere.

I'd have thought "Series" would map onto a type of "TV Series" quite nicely and then "TV Series" would have property like "video:show" which would link to a "TV Show".

So can anyone explain what this 'series' type is, and what this type column means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Facebooks documentation of the object 'TV Show', it is considered a series.

In regards to what it is used for; series would in this case map to the object 'TV Show'.

As a basic example of using the field, assuming that your action is pulling data from a page with the type 'video.episode' in the meta tag markup, you will also need to get the data for the series.  The series field is used to hold a link to a separate page that holds the data for the series itself rather than individual episode.

Episode markup

```
  <meta property="fb:app_id"      content="app_id" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"        content="video.episode" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"         content="www.show.com/show_1/e/1" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"       content="tv_episode_title" /> 
  <meta property="video:series" content="www.show.com/show_1" />
```

Show Markup

```
  <meta property="fb:app_id"      content="app_id" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"        content="video.tv_show" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"         content="www.show.com/show_1" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"       content="tv_show_1" />
```

[Facebook TV Show Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/video.tv_show/)

[Facebook TV Episode Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/video.episode/)

Comment: Thanks I never found those docs before. Bit confusing how it's named series not show!

Comment: Not a problem. I literally just finished a project using similar objects. Facebook documentation is a hassle in general so I wish you the best of luck in development.